# Does it matter what color format an image has when saving it as PNG?

Tags: iphone, ios, png

I am creating tiles for a larger image and I'm saving them to disk. Question: Is there any way I can optimize the image so that reading and decompressing the PNG from disk is faster? Possibly by changing the order or color bytes in the color space on a custom bitmap context from which the image is saved?

```
UIImage *fullSizeImage = [self cachedImageWithURL:imageURL];
CGRect tileRect = (CGRect){{column*tileSize.width, row*tileSize.height}, {tileSize.width, tileSize.height}};
CGRect totalRect = (CGRect){CGPointZero, fullSizeImage.size};
tileRect = CGRectIntersection(tileRect, totalRect);
CGImageRef tileImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([fullSizeImage CGImage], tileRect);
UIImage *retImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:tileImage];
[self.cache setObject:retImage forKey:cacheURL cost:0];
[retImage savePNGAsyncToURL:cacheURL];
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you would do it, but excluding the alpha channel when not used would be helpful. It would result in reduced file size. Also it would be especially useful for performance when drawing the image which isn't your main goal here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've benchmarked this, and it looks that speed is closely correlated to file size (smaller file is faster):

http://imageoptim.com/tweetbot.html

If you're OK with lossy compression, then use [pngquant](http://pngquant.org) to create those files. At 8bpp they'll have 1/4th of data to begin with.